# Sending commands to screen: limits of "stuff", quirks w/ newlines

Tags: bash, sh, gnu-screen

Trying to pass a long command string to Screen via the "stuff" option.  Have done this successfully in many scripts when the string is short and it exists in the in bash, like so:

```
screen -d -m -S worker
screen -S worker -X -p 0 stuff $'/usr/bin/env python3 /root/worker.py\n'
```

In this case, I am reading the command from a file.  I can append '\n' to that file but the $ () constructor eats the newlines.  I have tried printf, ISF=, and many permutations but where I can preserve newlines, somehow the command won't make it to screen.

```
GEO_COMMAND=/foo/geo_command.txt
screen -S worker -X -p 0 stuff printf '%\n' "$GEO_COMMAND"
or
screen -S worker -X -p 0 stuff $GEO_COMMAND
```

GEO_COMMAND: ''foo -bar -geo1 -geo2 -blah -keys ..... 160 characters later ...; /root/finish_job.sh\n '

Answer is highlighted below, adding this for posterity:

screen 'stuff' option does not like large commands and is very particular regarding newlines.

Comments / answers below solved the reliable newline issue but to paste / execute large commands, the answer is to use 'readreg' to read in a text file with the command, then pass that to screen using a second command with 'paste', as indicated below.

This approach requires no trailing newlines, does not require you to wrap your command (in the file) with quotes, and will accept conductive commands (; /foo/bar/sh) as well.

Comment: You can concatenate strings simply by juxtaposing them; each string can use a different style of quoting. For example, `screen ... "$GEO_COMMAND"$'\n'`

Comment: Please put that in the question.

Comment: It would be something like `GEO_COMMAND="..."$'\n'`. You aren't actually adding a newline to the value, just a digraph consisting of a backslash and an `n`.

Comment: added - sorry about that.  The concatenation helps by reliably adding a newline to make the command be executed.  What is odd is that the command now also causes bash to throw an error in the screen:  no such file or directory.  If I copy / paste the same command, it executes in that screen with no errors = does not make sense to me

Comment: Can you explain `GEO_COMMAND = /foo/geo_command.txt` ? With the spaces around `=` bash will be looking to a command called GEO_COMMAND, so `GEO_COMMAND=/foo/geo_command.txt` might be better. However, I think you want to add the content of the file, si I think you want `GEO_COMMAND=$(cat /foo/geo_command.txt)` or without the additional variable `screen -S worker -X -p 0 stuff $(cat /foo/geo_command.txt)`.

Comment: Walter - force of habit (python), but no spaces in the bash -tc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `screen` man page suggests that `stuff` should not be used for large strings. As an alternative you can read a file into a register (a sort of buffer) and then paste it. Here, `p` is the arbitrary register:

```sh
screen -S worker -X readreg p /foo/geo_command.txt
screen -S worker -X paste p
```

This more direct method has the advantage that you don't need to go via an intermediate shell variable, as in `GEO_COMMAND="$(cat ...)"`, which loses the final newline. Also, the data is not interpreted by `screen` (e.g. the 2 characters `\n` in the file is not replaced by a 1 character newline).

Comment: boom - works like a charm.  man says:  'You cannot paste large buffers with the "stuff" command...' but never defines large!  This works.  Would you be so kind as to edit the commands above for posterity in three ways:  (1) please make them 'screen -S plotter -X ...." which is the convention,  (2) note that this obviates the need to read in my GEO_COMMAND into bash in any prior step, and (3) that this needs absolutely no tricks with newline to work -- a .txt file with no trailing newline will be executed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As you already found out `$(cmd)` removes trailing newlines from `cmd`'s output and there is no way to stop this behavior.

As a workaround, you can append a trailing newline after the `$()`.

```
screen -S worker -X -p 0 stuff "$(cat yourFile)"$'\n'
```

However, this might behave unexpectedly because `screen stuff` interprets control sequences like `^C` and `\n` before typing them into your session. Therefore it might be wiser to source your script file, assuming the filename itself does not contain any special symbols:

```
screen -S worker -X -p 0 stuff '. yourFile\n'
```

Comment: This helps, as per chepner's comment above: it reliably adds a newline.  I've tried his format (exactly, below) and yours (as you typed).

Both of these cause plotter to throw a "no such file or directory" complaint, which is not believable, as copy/paste/enter of same command in screen *works*.  I'm thinking there is something screen-ey missing..

    GEO_COMMAND=$(<$ACCEPTED_FILE)
    screen -S plotter -X -p 0 stuff "$GEO_COMMAND"$'\n'

Comment: I don't think this is a problem of this approach, but of the commands inside your file. Please try to find out which command produces the error message (`set -x` might help). Once you found the problematic command and cannot fix it yourself, open a new question.

Comment: @ToddCurry On the other hand, I just found out that `screen stuff` interprets control sequences like `^C` and `\n` (the literal strings). Maybe that caused your error. I edited the answer with a workaround. Usually I'd write a quoting mechanism, but I couldn't find a description of what `screen stuff` interprets, so that would be a wild guessing game.

Comment: Socowi, issue appears to be that the command was just too large to pass to screen and it was likely munged.  Many thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

a small addition to the answer.
stuff is first echoing the command, then it's putting it on the command line, and then executes it if the \n or ^M ends the line.

since the echo annoyed me, i've chained \nclear\n as the last command, so the screen window starts clean.